# How to integrate React js with Ghost CMS? - Knowledge Share

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, ghost-blog

## **This question is a self-answer. Writing this for updating the community’s collective knowledge.**

If a user wants to add React component to their existing Ghost template without creating new react app, how can they add that?

I searched the internet for solutions on how to add React into plain HTML. Then looked into how I can add that into the handlebars template that Ghost CMS uses. Then understood how webpack and babel work and why they are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrate React with Ghost you will need the following -

1. **Babel** - it is a transpiler to convert ECMAScript2015+ into backwards-compatible JavaScript, to convert JSX into plain JS.
2. **Webpack** - it is a module bundler to bundle your React JS files together to be imported in your Ghost blog as a tag. It is what will run babel.

Prior knowledge of webpack and babel is important. You can learn what is required within a day.

Once you feel you are comfortable with Babel and Webpack, follow the link - https://medium.com/@tranvu/integrating-webpack-into-the-casper-theme-ghost-b68b49a073b4

***TODO: I will be adding step-by-step guide and code later.***